# TYPO3. Add new page type with typeNum to TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typenum

I have this error in my extension:

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #129458537: The page is not configured! [type=100][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=102 configured

So I want to add a new typeNum = 100 to the TypoScript, with a message to display in the FE, but dunno how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define new typeNums in TypoScript like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page {
   # set properties ...
}

msg = PAGE
msg.typeNum = 100
msg {
   10 = TEXT
   10.value = My special message.
}
```

See: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

The common site-setup looks like this:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  typeNum = 0
  [FURTHER SETUP]
}
```

any alternative page needs another name and another `typeNum`:

```
altPage = PAGE
altPage {
  typeNum = 100
  [FURTHER SETUP]
}

altPage2 = PAGE
altPage2 {
  typeNum = 102
  [FURTHER SETUP]
}
```

The `FURTHER SETUP` must include some kind of template to show:

```
altPage2 = PAGE
altPage2 {
  typeNum = 102
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  10 {
  ...
  }
}
```

**LINKS to documentation:**

- [TypoScript Page](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html)
- [TypoScript Template](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Template/Index.html)
- [TypoScript FluidTemplate](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html)

Let me know in the comments if it's sufficient for you. Else I can add a bit more description, links or TypoScript.

Comment: Thank you, I thinkthat's sufficient, I will try,  what I need is the display a message (like 'Päge Not Found') instead of giving an error

Comment: An Error page you can show without a special page-type.
In the Backend: Site-Management -> Sites -> Error Handling you can configure one site for every error.